# How to compute rolling average in pandas just for a specific date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have this example dataframe below. I created a function that does what I want, computing a `Sales` rolling average (7,14 days window) for each `Store` for the previous day and shifts it to the current date. How can I compute this **only** for a specific date, `2022-12-31`, for example? I have a lot of rows and I don't want to recalculate it each time I add a date.

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ex = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2022-10-01', '2022-12-31'), 
                   'Store': np.random.choice(2, len(pd.date_range('2022-10-01', '2022-12-31'))),
                   'Sales': np.random.choice(10000, len(pd.date_range('2022-10-01', '2022-12-31')))})

ex.sort_values(['Store','Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

for days in [7, 14]:
    ex['Sales_mean_' + str(days) + '_days'] = ex.groupby('Store')[['Sales']].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1).rolling(days).mean().shift(-days+1))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redefined a similar dataframe because using a random variable generator makes debugging difficult. At each test the dataframe changes randomly.

In addition to keep it simple, I will use 2 and 3 moving average periods.

**Starting dataframe**

```
        Date  Store  Sales
9 2022-10-10      1   5347
8 2022-10-09      1   1561
7 2022-10-08      1   5648
6 2022-10-07      1   8123
5 2022-10-06      1   1401
4 2022-10-05      0   2745
3 2022-10-04      0   7848
2 2022-10-03      0   3151
1 2022-10-02      0   4296
0 2022-10-01      0   9028
```

It gives :

```py
ex = pd.DataFrame({
  "Date": pd.date_range('2022-10-01', '2022-10-10'),
  "Store": [0]*5+[1]*5,
  "Sales": [9028, 4296, 3151, 7848, 2745, 1401, 8123, 5648, 1561, 5347],
})

ex.sort_values(['Store','Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

**Proposed code**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ex = pd.DataFrame({
  "Date": pd.date_range('2022-10-01', '2022-10-10'),
  "Store": [0]*5+[1]*5,
  "Sales": [9028, 4296, 3151, 7848, 2745, 1401, 8123, 5648, 1561, 5347],
})

ex.sort_values(['Store','Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

periods=(2,3)

### STEP 1 -- Initialization : exhaustive Mean() Calculation
for per in periods:
    ex["Sales_mean_{0}_days".format(per)] = (
        ex.groupby(['Store'])['Sales']
          .apply(lambda g: g.shift(-1)
                            .rolling(per)
                            .mean()
                            .shift(-per+1))
     )

### STEP 2 -- New Row Insertion
def fmt_newRow(g, newRow, periods):
    return {
      "Date": pd.Timestamp(newRow[0]),
      "Store": newRow[1],
      "Sales": newRow[2],
      "Sales_mean_{0}_days".format(periods[0]): g['Sales'].iloc[0:periods[0]].mean(),
      "Sales_mean_{0}_days".format(periods[1]): g['Sales'].iloc[0:periods[1]].mean(),
    }    

def add2DF(ex, newRow):
    # g : sub-Store group
    g = (
        ex.loc[ex.Store==newRow[1]]
          .sort_values(['Store','Date'], ascending=False)
    )
    # Append newRow like a dictionary and sort by ['Store','Date']
    ex = (
        ex.append(fmt_newRow(g, newRow, periods), ignore_index=True)
          .sort_values(['Store','Date'], ascending=False)
          .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
    #
    return ex

newRow = ['2022-10-11', 1, 2803] # [Date, Store, Sales]
ex = add2DF(ex, newRow)

print(ex)
```

**Result**

```
         Date  Store  Sales  Sales_mean_2_days  Sales_mean_3_days
0  2022-10-11      1   2803             3454.0        4185.333333
1  2022-10-10      1   5347             3604.5        5110.666667
2  2022-10-09      1   1561             6885.5        5057.333333
3  2022-10-08      1   5648             4762.0                NaN
4  2022-10-07      1   8123                NaN                NaN
5  2022-10-06      1   1401                NaN                NaN
6  2022-10-05      0   2745             5499.5        5098.333333
7  2022-10-04      0   7848             3723.5        5491.666667
8  2022-10-03      0   3151             6662.0                NaN
9  2022-10-02      0   4296                NaN                NaN
10 2022-10-01      0   9028                NaN                NaN
```

**Comments**

- A new row is a list like this one : `[Date, Store, Sales]`
- Each time you need to save a new row to dataframe, you pass it to `fmt_newRow` function with the corresponding subgroup `g`
- `fmt_newRow` returns a new row on the form of a dictionary which is integrated in the dataframe with `append` Pandas function
- No need to recalculate all the averages, because only the `per`-last `g` values are used to calculate the new row average
- Moving averages for periods 2 and 3 were checked and are correct.

Comment: The logic seems good but the computation when adding the row does not give the proper result. For example, for `2022-10-11` for Store 1 the `Sales_mean_2_days` should be `(5347+1561)/2 = 3604.5`, the same as for previous row : `(5648+1561)/2`. I changed the code below and it gives the right mean.

Comment: `"Sales_mean_{0}_days".format(periods[0]): g['Sales'].iloc[1:periods[0]+1].mean(),
 "Sales_mean_{0}_days".format(periods[1]): g['Sales'].iloc[1:periods[1]+1].mean(),`

Comment: @Rodix : I understand now the matter. Two hypothesis of work : Either you decide to include the actual value in the average calculation either not. These hypothesis were not clear for me in the question.

Comment: Date 2020-10-11, with the hypothesis including the actual value we have (2803+5347) / 2 = 4075 and with the other excluding the actual value, we have (5347+1561) / 2 = 3604.5. It's a matter of shift. Thus you could also do a ```shift()``` on averages columns.

Comment: Nevertheless, like there was a lag problem in the output, I rewrite using your suggestion with ```mean()``` but starting from 0 : ```g['Sales'].iloc[0:periods[0]].mean()```